# Can we connect many salesforce org, in heroku connect?

Tags: import, heroku, heroku-connect, heroku-enterprise

We want to transfer 3 salesforce orgs object record to another salesforce org Using heroku connect.
What should i do ? 
i have 3 developer edition salesforce. and free heroku account.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this a one time data transfer or you want to access other org's data instantly ?

Comment: One time data transfer.

Comment: I highly recommend Jitterbit studio for such operation. I never used Heroku for data migration.